# iOS App developed in flash builder 4.7 does not use full screen

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder

I have developed an iOS app in Flash Builder 4.7 using latest AIR SDK and iOS 7.0 sdk, when run in simulator/device it does not utilize 4" iphone 5S's display rather it looks like it is scaled to iPhone 4's screen size (3.5"). While creating an app I have selected 320 dpi, "requestedDisplayResolution>high /requestedDisplayResolution>", " fullScreen>true /fullScreen>".....

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the 4" Launch Image to utilize the entire 4" screen.

From [iPhone Development 101](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html):

> Note that the Default-568h@2x.png image is required for an app to display in full-screen mode on the iPhone 5.

You need to include these anyway (Apple will auto-reject your app without a launch image for both the 3.5" retina and 4" retina displays). Just add these images, named **exactly** what they are on that page to your `src` directory in Flash Builder and you should be good to go.